# How can I get elements to ignore margins?

Tags: html, css

My page has a small margin on the body to keep text from being to close to the edge of the screen. But the problem is I want divs to start and end on the edge of the screen  to get a effect like the purple on [this page](http://getbootstrap.com/). My divs have the IDs of "div1" and "div2" what can I add to my css to get the divs to ignore the margin of the body but still have every other element keep within the margin?

CSS:

```
*
{
   margin:3px:
}
```

Comment: override the margin values for the divs you don't want that margin value to apply to

Comment: Why not move the margin from the body to an element that contains the text? in that way there is no margin on the body to worry about for the purple div.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`*` applies to every element.

Why not try what you meant?

```
body {margin:3px}
```

You can then make the "purple area" with this:

```
.hug_the_edges {margin:0 -3px}
```

Comment: You can have negative margins? 0_0

Comment: @Qwertieϟ Yup! Can't tell you how often I use them!

Comment: @Wezly That's false, W3C says: "Negative values for margin properties are allowed, but there may be implementation-specific limits." Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#margin-properties

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason that you can't remove the margin from the `body` all together? ..I would - and then add the margin to another element that contains the text `#container`.

```
<style>

  body { margin:0px; }

  #container { margin:10px }

  #purple { width:100%; background-color:purple; color:white; padding:10px; min-height:200px; }

</style>

<body>

  <div id="purple">Some Text</div>

  <div id="container">Some Text</div>

</body>
```

Here is an example - http://jsfiddle.net/Ag3w6/1/

Answer (score -1):

You can use !important to ignore previous css mark up

```
*
{
   margin:3px:
}
div
{
   margin: 10px !important;
}
```